# Not able to save screenshot to report portal when executed using wdio

Tags: javascript, selenium, jenkins, webdriver-io

I have a webdriverio project with following structure.
e2e/
utilities/pUtil.js
report/screenshot
specs
wdio.config.js

I have the following in pUtil.js

```
static takeScreenshot(name, failure = false, test) {
    const path = './e2e/report/screenshot/';
    let fileName = '';
    if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(path, { recursive: true });
    }
    if (failure) {
      fileName = name + '_fail';
    }
    fileName = fileName.replace(/ /g, '_') + '.png';
    browser.saveScreenshot(path + fileName);
    const data = fs.readFileSync(`${path}${fileName}`);
    reporter.sendFileToTest(test, 'INFO', fileName, data);
  }
```

My project is configured for both allure and report portal reports.
When the test fails, a screenshot is successfully added to allure report but not report portal.

```
 ********* FILE NAME IN **********./e2e/report/screenshot/should_allow_us_fail.png
[2021-09-23T01:20:52.483Z] [0-0] ************ outputFile::./e2e/report/screenshot//should_allow_us_fail.png
[2021-09-23T01:20:52.483Z] [0-0] 2021-09-23T01:20:51.026Z ERROR @wdio/sync: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './e2e/report/screenshot/should_allow_us_fail.png'
[2021-09-23T01:20:52.483Z] [0-0]     at Object.openSync (fs.js:457:3)
[2021-09-23T01:20:52.483Z] [0-0]     at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:359:35)
```

Could some one please point out what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out !

use wdio  `after: function (result, capabilities, specs) {}` hook for spec file or WDIO `afterStep: async function (step, scenario, result, passed, error,duration) {}},` hook for cucumber to takeScreenshot for failed tests.

step 1: `npm i wdio-reportportal-reporter`
code snippet in WDIO config

```
const reportportal = require('wdio-reportportal-reporter');

after: async function (result, capabilities, specs) {
  if (!result) {
     const screenShot = await global.browser.takeScreenshot();
     let attachment = await Buffer.from(screenShot, 'base64');
     await reportportal.sendFile('error', "screnshot.png", attachment);
 }
},
```